# Conditional Rendering in ReactJs for one part in Html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to render some part of Html only if one of the variable is true. I have seen examples where I can return the whole element but I only want a if condition on one part of the html. I only want to show with 10 lines if one of the variables is true but html with 500 lines is common. Can I do that in return function?

```
const getCustomers= (props) => {
useEffect(() =>{ do something...});

 return (
<>
if(test === true){
<div> 10 lines</div>
else
{
do not show this div
}
}

<div> 500 lines</div> // Common
</>

)
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use conditional (ternary) operator

```
return (
 <>
  { test === true ? (<div> 10 lines</div>) : null }
  <div> 500 lines</div>
 </>

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Conditional rendering is only supported using [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and [logical and](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) operator:

```
{
  something ? '10 lines' : '500 lines'
}

{
  something && '10 lines' || '500 lines'
}
```

`if-else` statements don't work inside JSX. This is because JSX is just syntactic sugar for function calls and object construction.

For further details, you may read [this](https://react-cn.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html), and [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid logic inside of your return statements.

You can assign your conditional output to a JSX value, and always render it.

```
const Customers = () => {

  const optionalDiv = test === true && <div>10 lines</div>;

  return (
    <>
      {optionalDiv}
      <div>500 lines</div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: I would do the same way... Best solution from my view.

Answer (score 0):

I think just doing it like this should do it -

```
return (
    <>
        {test? <div> 10 lines</div> : null}
        <div> 500 lines which are common</div> 
    </>
);
```